# How can i use a hashtag (I like #running) as a link in a post?

Tags: mysql, hashtag

I am making a small social network site.. Like twitter and facebook people will post in this site with hashtags. When they submit their posts the hashtag words in their post will be seen as clickable links and that link will go to the hashtags page where other posts including same hashtag are displayed..

My question is how can i display a hashtag word in a post like a link which goes to its page.

Example:

if someone posts

I #love running under rain.

word #love will be displayed in different color and clickable and it href will be www.example.com/love

Answer (score 0):

Think of the hashtag as just another word you write in the HTML,

For you example it should look something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/love">#love</a>
```

That's the linking part

If you want to make it with color green for example it should look like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/love"><span style="color:green">#love</span></a>
```